# Relative Overlays with pgfkeys

Tags: beamer, overlays, pgfkeys

I would like to create relative overlays in `beamer` with a different notation than the existing one. The following code gives satisfying results.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\newcommand\getspec[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/#1/spec}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/1st item/spec}{1-2}
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/2nd item/spec}{2}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<\getspec{1st item}> Content
            \item<\getspec{2nd item}> More content
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Because keys in `pgfkeys` are local to the current group the following code throws an error `Missing number, treated as zero.`, because after the first frame-environment is left, the value of the key `1st item` is set to something like an empty string.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\newcommand\getspec[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/#1/spec}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/1st item/spec}{1-2}
        \pgfkeyssetvalue{/2nd item/spec}{2}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<\getspec{1st item}> Content
            \item<\getspec{2nd item}> More content
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<\getspec{1st item}> Content
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to adapt the code of `getspec` to give a more useful error message. Something like `this label has not been defined for the current frame` would be nice.

This is related to [Relative Order of Overlays in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230445/relative-order-of-overlays-in-beamer) and to [external link](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=25777&p=89545#p89545).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following kind of works:

```
\newcommand\getspec[1]{
    \pgfkeysifdefined{/#1/spec}{
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/#1/spec} % The key is defined
    }{ 0| stop:0| % Dirty hack
        \errmessage{Label "#1" has not been defined for the current frame}
    }
}
```

Which produces the following error:

```
! Label "1st item" has not been defined for the current frame.
\beamer@@@temp ...n defined for the current frame}
                                                    | stop:0| 
l.24 \end{frame}
```

The `| stop:0|` hack escapes from the Beamer parsing which expects numbers, but note that this might not work with every Beamer version.

Comment: I thought I tried `\pgfkeysifdefined`.. Anyway, thanks!