# \pause not working on includegraphics in beamer

Tags: pause

I have used following comment

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}


  \setbeamercovered{transparent}

}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\newtheorem{df}{Definition}[section]
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Theorem}
Theorem Text Here
\end{block}
\vfill \pause

\begin{block}{Corollary}
Corollary text here
\end{block}
\vfill \pause 
\begin{example}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{cross.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and the output is 
[image]

In this, figure is not fade.
I need figure become visible only after the corollary.

Identified that this will work if we remove  `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`. But i would like to know is this work without removing `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 12):

You need to apply an overlay specification specifically to the image. You can use `\visible<3>{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{cross.eps}}` to make the figure appear only on slide 3 of the frame. You can also use [relative overlay specifications](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154527/24974), like `\visible<.(1)>{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{cross.eps}}`. I'll use an example image in the code below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Theorem}
Theorem Text Here
\end{block}
\vfill \pause

\begin{block}{Corollary}
Corollary text here
\end{block}
\vfill \pause 
\begin{example}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\visible<.(1)>{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}}
\end{figure}
\end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Instead of hiding the image in the first slides, it can be shaded as well:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}{Theorem}
            Theorem Text Here
        \end{block}

        \vfill \pause

        \begin{block}{Corollary}
            Corollary text here
        \end{block}

        \vfill \pause 

        \begin{example} 
            \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \visible<1-2>{\node[opacity=0.3] (img2) {\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{pic}};}
            \visible<3>{\node (img2) {\includegraphics[height=0.4\textwidth]{pic}};}
        \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{figure}
        \end{example}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SeenaV: Instead of saying `Thank you` only, consider to accept one of the answers here!