# How to renew \frame so that only the title of a new frame is shown first?

Tags: beamer

Basically I want each new frame to show only its title first. I tried

> \renewcommand<>{\frame}[1]{\beameroriginal{\frame \pause #1}}

and variations, but it did not work.

Comment: So you use `\frame{ \frametitle{<title>} ... }` for your setup? Do you use `\begin{frame}{<title>} ... \end{frame}` at all?

Comment: I usually use \begin{frame}...\end{frame}. I am very new to beamer

Comment: You want to do this on *every* frame? If I were in your audience I would find that very distracting.

Comment: I'm going to present a math talk and thought that I would show a new empty slide with the name on top "Topic X". Then give some background in words about Topic X and only then show the formulas etc. I think this would help to get more attention to what I am talking about. At least for me, when I attend the talks and see a new slide I start reading immediately and then the words of the speaker are somewhere in the background

Answer (score 4):

Adding `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\pause}` to the preamble should do the trick.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\pause}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
Frame content
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Other frame title}
Other frame content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your MWE certainly works. However, I also use \pause in the frames and then everything gets messed up.


\documentclass{beamer}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\pause}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
Frame content
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Another frame}
 \begin{equation}
  x= y
 \end{equation}\pause
 
 \begin{equation}
  y=x
 \end{equation}
\end{frame}


\end{document}

Comment: @Gytis Yeah, I realized this as well. You may need to use [relative overlay specifications](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154521/24974) or an `\addtocounter` somewhere. I'll try to take a look at this again later.

Comment: maybe I'll just write some more \pause commands as it seems to be faster, unless one decides to start a slideshow factory. Don't worry too much