# How to replace a text on the next slide?

Tags: beamer

I want to replace a word by another one on the next slide. I know there are commands that allow to do so (say, \uncover), but they require to carefully calculate the numbers of the slides where the command is used. However, I intend to edit my presentation, which would mean that every time when the number of slides changes, I will have to edit all such comands. Are there simple ways to avoid the problem?

Comment: A traditional LaTeX way is, on the next slide, not to use the actual word, but a macro that points to a word, as in `here is \myword{} on the next slide`.  That way, on the prior slide, you could say `\def\myword{elephant}` and then, on the next slide, what would show up would be `here is elephant on the next slide`

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154521/relative-overlay-specification-in-beamer

Comment: http://www.texdev.net/2014/01/17/the-beamer-slide-overlay-concept/

Comment: http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-1/tb109wright.pdf

Comment: I am new in this business, may I ask you to give a simple example, please...

Comment: @Steven: I don't understand how to redefine the _elephant_ on the next slide.

Comment: Well, the way joseph interpreted your question is different than the way I interpreted it.  It would be best if you posted a complete but minimum working example of code to show what you had in mind.

Comment: I want to have _I see an elephant_ on the N-th slide, and _I see a giraffe_ on the slides no. N+1, N+2, and so on, until the end of the frame. That is, an elephant should be replaced by a giraffe.

Comment: "I am new in this business, may I ask you to give a simple example." From your question it sounds like you already have some working code. Please post your working code. And please point out which are the numbers you would prefer not to have to edit everytime you change something. Then someone will probably be able to post an answer based on Joseph Wright's first comment.

Comment: @Willie: this is a text of an article which I adapt for a presentation. Of course, the paper is not devoted to elephants.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{main title}{subtitle}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item foo
    \item bar \only<.>{baz}\only<+->{BAZ}
    \item foobar
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`<.>` the current slide

`<+->` the next and following slide

and without `itemize`

```
\begin{frame}{main title}{subtitle}
\only<1>{elephant}\only<2->{giraffe}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I am sure this works, but I meant a sentence, not an itemized structure... Is it possible to adapt it to my situation, which is like the following: I want to have _I see an elephant_ on the N-th slide, and _I see a giraffe_ on the slides no. N+1, N+2, and so on, until the end of the frame.

Comment: That makes no difference: `\includegraphics<.>{elephant}\includegraphics<+->{giraffe}`

Comment: I copied your code to my file, it says ! LaTeX Error: File `elephant' not found.

Comment: I gave an example with two images which I do not have! You have to adopt it and use image names which are exist on your system. For _words_  simply use `\only<.>{elephant}\only<+->{giraffe}`

Comment: Are you sure in \only<.>{elephant}\only<+->{giraffe} ? Elephant is not visible.

Comment: see extended answer

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `\alt` command. This displays either a default text or an alternate text, depending on the overlay specifications (see section 9.2 of the beamer documentation).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{main title}{subtitle}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item foo
    \item bar \alt<.>{baz}{BAZ}
    \item foobar
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```