# Table overflowing in a list in Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, lists

I am using Palo Alto theme for my beamer. I want to make a table as an item of a "description" list. But the table overflows to the right. How to resolve the issue?

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Stability Conditions}
\begin{description}[<+->]
\item[ODE] $a_2x''+a_1x'+a_0x=f(t)$
\item[Characteristic equation] $a_2m^2+a_1m+a_0=0$
\item \begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
$\textbf{roots}$ & $\textbf{solution}$ & $\textbf{stability condition}$\\
$m_1\neq m_2$ & $c_1e^{m_1t}+c_2e^{m_2t}$ & $m_1,m_2<0$\\
$m=m_1=m_2$ & $e^{mt}(c_1+c_2t)$ & $m<0$\\
$m_{1,2}=\alpha\pm\beta i$ & $e^{\alpha t}(c_1\cos{\beta t}+c_2\sin{\beta 
t})$ & $\alpha<0$
\end{tabular}
\caption{Stability in relation to the roots of the characteristic equation}
\end{table}
\end{description}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Why does the table need to be a list item when the item has no entry? I would just put the table below the list.

Comment: @erik I'm trying to use "pause" feature of lists in beamer

Comment: Doesn't pause work outside of lists?

Comment: Oh, and captions are conventionally above table and below figures. But it's just conventional, it's not like you have to or it'll be bad design or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply overlay specifications to almost anything in beamer, not just list items. You can indicate the slide specifically with something like `\visible<3->`, but also relatively (this is what the `[<+->]` means following your list). See the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154521/24974) for details on relative overlay specifications.

Give the following code a try.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Stability Conditions}
\begin{description}[<+->]
\item[ODE] $a_2x''+a_1x'+a_0x=f(t)$
\item[Characteristic equation] $a_2m^2+a_1m+a_0=0$
\end{description}
{\small
\visible<+->{%
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
$\textbf{roots}$ & $\textbf{solution}$ & $\textbf{stability condition}$\\
$m_1\neq m_2$ & $c_1e^{m_1t}+c_2e^{m_2t}$ & $m_1,m_2<0$\\
$m=m_1=m_2$ & $e^{mt}(c_1+c_2t)$ & $m<0$\\
$m_{1,2}=\alpha\pm\beta i$ & $e^{\alpha t}(c_1\cos{\beta t}+c_2\sin{\beta 
t})$ & $\alpha<0$
\end{tabular}
\caption{Stability in relation to the roots of the characteristic equation}
\end{table}
}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]