# Renumber in \only<x> beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have a frame with some text popping and transfoming as slides are flowing using only :

```
\begin{frame}
  A is 
  \only<1>{Y}
  \only<2>{Z}
\end{frame}
```

Assume that I want to add first an X in my text, popping before Y, I cannot do

```
\only<0>{X}
```

Is there a way to renumber properly in `\only`?

Comment: You want the relative specification. I've covered some of it in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154521/relative-overlay-specification-in-beamer, but perhaps that answer is too complicated here: if it doesn't help, I'll write some basics up.

Comment: Try with `\only<+>{...}` instead of hard coded numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, what you want is a relative specification. The `beamer` class supports them using the `+` syntax. Thus for example your example could be made into

```
\begin{frame}
  A is 
  \only<+>{Y}
  \only<+>{Z}
\end{frame}
```

and then into

```
\begin{frame}
  A is
  \only<+>{X} 
  \only<+>{Y}
  \only<+>{Z}
\end{frame}
```

Each time `+` is found, it is replaced by an incremented slide number: the first use is therefore slide 1. There is a lot of subtlety to this process, which I've covered in [Relative overlay specification in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154521/relative-overlay-specification-in-beamer).