# Why does replacing <+-> with <2-> create a second slide?

Tags: beamer

The document

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \begin{block}{First Block}
    Some text.
  \end{block}

  \onslide<2->
  \begin{block}{Second Block}
    More Text
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Only produces one slide. Changing `\onslide<+->` to `\onslide<2->` produces two slides. Why is this?

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154521/relative-overlay-specification-in-beamer/154527#154527 help?

Answer (score 3):

I quote the  section *9.6.4 Incremental Specifications* of 3.55 manual (page 91):

> The effect of the `+`sign is the following: You can use it in any
>   overlay specification at any point where you would usually use a
>   number. If a `+`sign is encountered, it is replaced by the current
>   value of the LATEX counter `beamerpauses`, which is `1` at the beginning
>   of the frame.

Then:

- when you write `\onslide<+->`, it is replaced by `\onslide<1->`which does not create an additional frame.
- when you write `\onslide<2->`, this creates a second frame.
- if you wrote `\onslide<3->`, there would then be a third frame.