# How to use overlays with different overprint slides including items, with automatic sequence numbers <+-> in beamer?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am working under LyX but of course my question is also for LaTeX. I want to do this:

```
\begin{overprint}
\only<1>{
Test in slide 1
}
\only<2-4>{
Test in slide 2 with items :
\begin{itemize}
\item<3-4> item 1
\item<4> item 2
\end{itemize}
}
\only<5>{
Test in slide 3
}
\end{overprint}
```

where `Test in slide 1` is replaced by `Test in slide 2` with its items showing one by one, and so on, `Test in slide 3` replacing all of them.

In a complex frame, I need using automatic slide numbering (`<+->`) instead of static sequence numbers. I have expected the following to work:

```
\begin{overprint}
\only<+->{
Test in slide 1
}
\only<+--+(2)->{
Test in slide 2 with items :
\begin{itemize}
\item<+--+(1)-> item 1
\item<+-> item 2
\end{itemize}
}
\only<+->{
Test in slide 3
}
\end{overprint}
```

But it does not compile:

```
[1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   -
l.152 \end{frame}

I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   >
l.152 \end{frame}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
.....
```

If I do this:

```
\begin{overprint}
\only<+->{
Test in slide 1
}
\only<+->{
Test in slide 2 with items :
\begin{itemize}
\item<+-> item 1
\item<+-> item 2
\end{itemize}
}
\only<+->{
Test in slide 3
}
\end{overprint}
```

then it compiles but the behaviour is not the one expected, the slides are added one after the other instead of replacing the previous one, as if I had used `\item` instead of `overprint` and `\only`.

What should I do please?

Here is the full Lyx code as an screenshot since the text one is bearely readable:

[image]

In this code, `<+-+>` is a strange attempt that make it work for slides 1 and 2, but not the 3rd one:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were rather close, I think. You had a few `-` too much. A very nice set of explanations can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154527/121799).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Absolute numbers}
\begin{overprint}
\only<1>{
Test in slide 1
}
\only<2-4>{
Test in slide 2 with items :
\begin{itemize}
\item<3-4> item 1
\item<4> item 2
\end{itemize}
}
\only<5>{
Test in slide 3
}
\end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Relative numbers}
\begin{overprint}
\only<+>{
Test in slide 1
}
 \only<+-+(2)>{
Test in slide 2 with items :
\begin{itemize}
\item<+-+(1)> item 1
\item<+> item 2
\end{itemize}
}
\only<+(2)>{
Test in slide 3
}
\end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]