# How to choose into which column to write in beamer without overlays?

Tags: beamer, multicolumn

I would like to write text in a three column frame under beamer, but not in default sequence starting inside the first column, and when it is filled in the next one, and so on. Instead, I would like to force beamer to fill this column with  this text, and to be able to choose for each piece of text.

I don't want to use overlays here because I use then for other purposes and it becomes an unsolved mess (cf [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490762/how-to-tackle-complex-overlays-with-columns-blocs-overprints-and-items))

Here is a pseudo code:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{My title}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
    \end{column}
    \col(2){1st text in column 2}
    \col(1){1st text in column 1}
    \col(2){2nd text in column 2}
    \col(3){1st text in column 3}
    \col(2){3rd text in column 2}
    \col(3){2nd text in column 3}
    \col(1){2nd text in column 1}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The traditional approach is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{My title}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
    \uncover<2->{1st text in column 1}
    \uncover<7->{2nd text in column 1}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
    {1st text in column 2}
    \uncover<3->{2nd text in column 2}
    \uncover<5->{3rd text in column 2}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.33\textwidth}
    \uncover<4->{1st text in column 3}
    \uncover<6->{2nd text in column 3}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution uses overlays, which is not desired. Though, I am going to test my complex overlay frame with it and if it works I will adopt it of course

Comment: unfortunately, it brings nothing to my [unsolved mess](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490762/how-to-tackle-complex-overlays-with-columns-blocs-overprints-and-items). I really need a solution without overlays