# How to mention the predecessor/successor of an overlay in an overlay specification?

Tags: beamer, overlays

Minimal example:

```tex
\begin{frame}

  \newcommand \ovStepA 1
  \newcommand \ovStepB 4
  \newcommand \ovStepC 9

  \newcommand \predOf[1] {%
    % ???
  }
  \newcommand \succOf[1] {%
    % ???
  }

  \only<-\predOf\ovStepB>{visible until step B (excluded)} % should expand to \only<-3>{...}
  \only<\ovStepB->{visible from step B (included)}

  \only<-\ovStepC>{visible up to step C (included)}
  \only<\succOf\ovStepC->{visible after step C (excluded)} % should expand to \only<10->{...}

\end{frame}
```

Do overlay specifications have a syntax for that (similarly to how Git lets you refer to the predecessor of `HEAD` as `HEAD^`, for instance), or otherwise how to have `\predOf` and `\succOf` run some basic arithmetic?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154521/relative-overlay-specification-in-beamer perhaps? It seems you are trying to recreate the idea of relative overlays without using the tools in `beamer`.

Comment: Off topic: please don't use e.g. `\newcommand \ovStepA 1`, which relies on how `\newcommand` is defined to add the braces that TeX requires: this should be `\newcommand\ovStepA{1}`.

Comment: Off-topic (bis): TeX is so hopeless… Not only `{ }` are not just parentheses, now I’m learning that spaces are significant syntax tokens. Why, why, why…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\inteval` (from `xfp` pakage):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xfp}
\newcommand\predOf[1]{\inteval{#1-1}}
\newcommand\succOf[1]{\inteval{#1+1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  
  \newcommand\ovStepA{1}
  \newcommand\ovStepB{4}
  \newcommand\ovStepC{9}
  
  \only<-\predOf{\ovStepB}>{visible until step B (excluded)}
  \only<\ovStepB->{visible from step B (included)}

  \only<-\ovStepC>{visible up to step C (included)}
  \only<\succOf{\ovStepC}->{visible after step C (excluded)}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]