# Relative overlay specification in Beamer: How it works?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have read the questions on this web over this topic of relative overlay specifications in Beamer, concretely [Relative Overlay Clarification](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154521/relative-overlay-specification-in-beamer), plus Beamer manual, some blog posts and what not.

And I must confess that I think I do not understand this well. For what I could see, when you write something like `<+->` as an overlay command, you should expect the command or text to be rendered one slide after the previous.

But when I compile the following code, I do not observe the expected result:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, 12pt, c]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
Blah, blah,\dots (First slide)
\onslide<+->{¡Hola! (Should it be the second slide?)}
\onslide<+->{Perhaps third? No clear\dots}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Actually, it creates a first slide with the text of the first `onslide` in it, *¡Hola! (Should it be the second slide?)*, and a second and final slice with this, and the last text, *Perhaps third? No clear...*.

I will consider that it should produce a first slide without **any** text from the `onslide` commands, then a second slide with the first `onslide` text, and so on.
Am I interpreting wrong the overlay specifications? I assume that, but I would like further clarification from experts.

Comment: As I detail in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154521/relative-overlay-specification-in-beamer?noredirect=1&lq=1, `+` is replaced by the current counter value, _then_ increments the counter, so the first `+` is _always_ replaced by `1` unless you mess with the counter

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the answer, but I think I understand this correctly. And then I have a doubt. How could I first, render some text and later start to put `onslide` consecutively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I now have clear this question and I would like to put it here for future reference, because althougth the linked question says it all, it does so in a way that is not always easy to understand to me.

First of all, overlays specifications using `\onslide` work over all the code *after* the specification and *until* the next piece of code with overlays. This means that usually is not necessary to use them with brackets, unless you want to do ***really*** strange things.

Second, symbol `+` maintains the counter and then increments its value, so it renders what comes later **in the previous slide**, and later increments the counter for the other slides.
This means that using and overlay specification like `<+->` will render in the same slide its code and later add 1 to the framecounter.

Then, if there is a situation in which some previous text has been rendered and there is a need for text, or any code, **in the next slide**, specification must be `<+(1)->`.
In this way frame counter is added **before** render the text.
If more code would need to be sequentially rendered, then the overlay specification `<+(1)->` must be added.

This minimal workind example shows a frame with some text in the first slide, and then sequentially other parts of it, employing relative overlays:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Test frame}
First slide: Blah, blah,\dots

\onslide<+(1)-> Second slide, with text \textbf{after} the first line has been rendered.

%From this line on, slides will continue because there is an "\onslide" command, like in the previous line...:
\onslide<+(1)-> Third slide, because again I add 1 to the frame counter before I render it.

\onslide<+(1)-> And this the forth, for the same reson than the previous\dots

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Finally, Joseph Wright has written as a consequence of the question about overlays linked before called *Relative Overlay Clarification* a good long explanation of the overlays, so I linked it here for the readers interested in expand what is here written: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-1/tb109wright.pdf (and my own reference).